# Are questions about cashbasha a spamming scheme, or just a coincidence?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, spam

Since yesterday, I encountered two different questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41352545/2422776) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41359838/2422776)) from two different users asking how to make a site like cashbasha, with the site's name linked to cashbasha.com (I did not follow the links, so no idea what's going on there).

As noted, these questions were from two different users, but the questions themselves have a "spammy" feel - a link to an external site, low-quality questions (too broad for SO).

What's the right course of action here? Flag as spam? Raise a custom flag? Something else?

Comment: I am not too sure about this. Both questions have been deleted though (~5 minutes after this question was posted), so I assume matters have been taken care of. Generally speaking this doesn't seem like spam to me. Could very well be wrong though.

Comment: I had a look at cashbasha.com. It's a service that allows people in Jordan and Saudi Arabia to  pay cash for amazon purchases (i.e. you hand over the cash and they order for you). It is at least conceivable that this is a legit business if you have a large population of people without credit cards and/or bank accounts (and would ne pointless as spam since outside those two countries you cannot use the site in any case).

Comment: As we've [seen this question also earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992400/how-to-embed-an-external-webpage-without-using-iframe), I would guess this is a topic that raises some legitimate interest.

Comment: @Seth that would be the meta-effect in full force

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Two questions does not yet a spamming scheme make. I agree that it raises an eyebrow, but I could discern no other indicators for it being any sort of scheme. The most likely explanation, apart from pure coincidence, is that the site made the news somewhere and several people stumbled across it at once.

However, these were some very poor questions which would have been removed sooner or later anyway, so I did that preemptively.